# Exception while reading xls file. Initialisation of record 0x10(DeltaRecord) left 8 bytes remaining still to be read

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I got the below error while reading the data from the `.xls` file.

**Error**

> org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$LeftoverDataException:
>   Initialisation of record 0x10(DeltaRecord) left 8 bytes remaining
>   still to be read. at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.hasNextRecord(RecordInputStream.java:178)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:494)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:356)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:319)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:266)
>   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:236)

**Code** which I have used.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int lastCol = sheet.getLastRowNum();
System.out.println(lastCol);
```

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where did this file come from? If you open it in Excel and do Save-As, does that fix the file?

Comment: I got the issue only in that file. Other excel file is working perfectly.

Comment: int lastCol = sheet.getLastRowNum(); If you want a last col number why are you using .getLastRowNum() ? I believe that the sheet.getLastRowNum() returns a value greater than 32,767, which is not supported by primitive int type